# Email unsubscribe link: How to detect a real person, so that a mail link-checking robot (gmail, antivirus) doesn't unsubscribe users accidentally?

Tags: javascript, email

I noticed a following pattern in e-mails sent from Mailchimp:

They would like to

- let users unsubscribe from e-mail by a single click (= clicking a link in e-mail, with no further confirmation needed on a website)
- but prevent mail-checking bots (gmail, antivirus ...) that open URLs mentioned in e-mail to accidentally unsubscribe their user

What they do now is pretty clever:

- An unsubscribe page does contain an unsubscribe button (so that a bot only sees the page, and doesn't do a destructive action just by visiting url)
- But when a page is opened by a real person, they click the button automatically, so the user sees just a quick loading indicator and then a confirmation of a successful unsubscribe.

I would like to implement a similar thing, but I am not sure how - is it only enough to 'click' a button with javascript?
This would assume that no link-checking bot runs javascript, and I'm not sure this is an assumption I can make.

Or, is there some other way of detecting that a real human is looking at page? Like, detecting mouse movement? Or scroll?

Thank you for ideas! :)

Comment: wouldn't it be that the agent is different between a bot and a browser?

Comment: I imagine when a mail-checking bots use different headers than standard web browsers. You might try requesting the Mailchimp unsubscribe page with a modified User-Agent, for example, and see how it responds.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of checking the mouse is pretty clever. If you have an onmousemove event coupled with an onmouseover event, you can detect if someone has moved a mouse to click on the button. Once you confirm you can send that along with your unsubscribe event. You might have to capture some real data, but I think just looking at the variance in the path would be sufficient to reject a bot unless it was specifically constructed to unsubscribe someone.

I would however test this with a frontend testing framework like selenium to make sure you can reject the clicks from an automated system.